# My system turns off automatically after 2 seconds of power on

Tags: windows-7, windows

My PC has Windows 7. After I switch on the PC, the desktop POSTs on and the monitor displays motherboard details.

Suddenly I get "No signal" message.

If I try again I get the same problem.

Comment: Can you give more information about your machine?

Comment: Any beeps when the computer starts up? If so, what's the pattern (ex. long beep + two short)?

Answer (score 6):

Something is broken.
It doesn't get to the the actual startup of Windows, it fails the hardware tests before that.
As a safety precaution it will shut itself off before more damage is done.

Without further details it is impossible to make a full diagnoses.

Possible (most common) causes:

- Bad RAM (or not seated properly in the slot).
- Video-card or other card not seated properly.
- Malfunctioning cooler causing overheating (this can happen in just seconds so just turning the machine on might get it warm enough) or if the fan is not turning at all the BIOS check may have detected this.

Does it beep before it shuts down ? If so the motherboard manual (or the website of the motherboard manufacturer) should list the failure cause indicated by the beep-pattern.